# Error when leaving an empty email input field clear

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a form on a .ctp which has multiple input fields. One of those input fields is an type="email" field. When submitting, that field is not important for me and i tried many ways of allowing that field to remain empty but it still bugs me with an error that "This value is already in use".
Below is how my input look like in the page, with the given error:

[image: form error]

And this is how my input looks like in the .ctp:

```
    <tr style="height:30px;">
        <td style="width: 160px;"><?= 'E-mail' ?></td>
        <td>
            <?= $this->Form->input('email',['empty' => false, 'label' => false, 'required' => false]); ?>
        </td>
        <td style="width:75px;"></td>
        <td class="edit_hints" style="border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;">Completează cu adresa de e-mail a persoanei de contact.</td>
    </tr>
```

And this is what my $validator looks like:

```
    $validator
        ->email('email')
        ->allowEmpty('email')
        ->requirePresence('email', false);
```

As you can see, i have tried everything I have researched and this problem still bugs me. What I am thinking is, that the email validator might find the empty value in another row in my db and it may resemble this error. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: In the db table email field has UNIQUE index?

Comment: No, it does not have any constraint on it and it can also be NULL. (my db is managed in PostegreSQL by the way)

Comment: Make sure that you don´t have buildRules like this in your table 

`public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
        return $rules;
    }`

Comment: This was the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JacekBBudzyñski Please add that as an answer, otherwise the question should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you don´t have buildRules like this in your table

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules) { 

    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email'])); 
    return $rules; 

}
```